# why does my output doesnt show the 'while' statement. the while statement is for displaying all the information

Tags: c++

Above the `while` statement, there's a `for` statement (input from user). Can you help?
I want to display the result using while. but the compiler didn't show it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Cat
{
       std::string name;
       float weight;
       int age;
};

main()
{
      int i=0;
      Cat P [5];

      for ( i=0; i<5; i++)
      {
          std::cout<<"Enter your pet name: ";
          std::cin>>P[i].name;
          std::cout<<"Enter your pet age: ";
          std::cin>>P[i].weight;
          std::cout<<"Enter your pet weight: ";
          std::cin>>P[i].weight;
      } 

      while (i<5)
      {
            std::cout<<"Pet name: "<<P[i].name<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"Pet age: "<<P[i].age<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"Pet weight: "<<P[i].weight<<std::endl;

            i++;
      }

      system("PAUSE");
      return 0;

}
```

Comment: It depends upon the value of `i`. Please initialize the value of `i` less than 5.

Comment: i already initialize it above the for statement earlier. but still, no output.

Comment: Show us a more complete code, we can't help you assuming things. Initialize them properly.

Comment: Your for loop must be changing the value of i then.

Comment: You might have used the variable i for some other purpose also. For example in your for loop. Initialize i immediately before the while loop.

Comment: Can you post your complete code?

Comment: there, i have copied the exact code i made

Comment: Put i = 0 before your while statement.

Comment: After the `for` loop (which also uses the `i` variable), `i` will retain a value of `5`. That's why your `while` statement will never be executed. Always use different variables for different statements (unless that's the behavior you want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reinitialize variable `i`, as once `for loop` is completed it value gets set to 5.

Comment: but then the error says 'int i reinitialize'

Comment: `i = 0;` simply write this statement before `while(i<5)`.

Comment: For giving more accurate information, "reinitialize" is usually used as "assigning an initial value again", that is, set its value to `0` in this case, using `i = 0;`. When you create the variable, using `int i;`, you are **declaring** a variable. When you write `int i = 0;`, you are **declaring** and then **initializing** the variable with a value (initializing is more commonly used just as **assigning a value**).

Answer (score 2):

set value of i to 0 after for loop 
ex:

```
for ( i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    std::cout<<"Enter your pet name: ";
    std::cin>>P[i].name;
    std::cout<<"Enter your pet age: ";
    std::cin>>P[i].weight;
    std::cout<<"Enter your pet weight: ";
    std::cin>>P[i].weight;
} 
i=0;
while (i<5)
{
    std::cout<<"Pet name: "<<P[i].name<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Pet age: "<<P[i].age<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Pet weight: "<<P[i].weight<<std::endl;
    i++;
}
```

i hope it will work..